# extracting data using NOT IN

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql, and came across a little problem.
I have a query that goes like this:

```
select cust_id, count(1) from all_customers
group by cust_id
having count(1)>4;
```

that query gives me the result i want.

I need to make a new query of all the customers in `all_customers` table, and exclude the result I just got from the query above.
I tried doing something like this:

```
select * from all_customers
where cust_id NOT IN 
(
    select cust_id, count(1) from all_customers
    group by cust_id
    having count(1)>4
)
```

But I get the error message `too many values`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get rid of the *aggregated* column in your `NOT IN` clause. The reason is you are only comparing `cust_id` column. Also note that when using `NOT IN`, a subquery should always return single column.

```
select * 
from all_customers
where cust_id NOT IN 
      (
         select cust_id 
         from all_customers
         group by cust_id
         having count(1)>4
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are to many columns in subquery, try:

```
select * from all_customers
where cust_id NOT IN 
(select cust_id
 from all_customers
 group by cust_id
 having count(1)>4)
```